Terminate Telegram Bot When JavaFX closes
I have a JavaFX project where I implemented TelegramBot extending TelegramLongPollingBot.
Everything works fine but I noticed that when I close the App gui in eclipse, there are still remaining Threads (specifically myTGBot Telegram Executor alongside other daemon threads).
How to terminate registered Telegram Bots?
I found that executing System.exit(0); terminates all threads created by my App; But what if I only want to stop my Bot and start it again;
I have a settings dialog where the user can insert BotName and BotToken; so what if I want to reinitiate the telegram bot if the user decides to change the bot credentials without fully restarting the app?
I tried to create and register myTGBot in a specific thread tGThread and call tGThread.interrupt() method when my JavaFx stage.setOnCloseRequest() is called.
but this doesn't work;
I searched but I couldn't find a solution for this issue.
I found how to terminate all the child Threads created by my Main class but how to properly terminate Telegram bots?

Application::stop "is called when the application should stop…" Also consider a javafx.concurrent.Service<V>.

If you run the bot in a daemon thread, it should exit when the application exits. Stopping it under any other circumstances would need the API you are using to have specific functionality to cancel it.

Thanks for the information, I need to read about javafx.concurrent.Service
Thanks a lot, instantiating the Bot in a daemon thread solves the issue of Threads being left after closing the javafx gui. But I still need to close the bot and register a new one without having to close the app.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
